# Error returning value from overloaded function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, arbitrary-precision

I am working through a resource I found online for writing a library to handle arbitrary precision numbers.

I have created the two files `BigInt.h`, containing the definitions of all the functions, and `BigInt.cpp`, containing all the implementations of the functions.

Part of the program involves overloading an operator to return a call from a different function.  For the sake of the question, I'll post the code as it comes from the example, even though I don't exactly understand why it works.

I define the operator overload here:

```
BigInt BigInt::operator / (const BigInt &v) const {
    return divmod(*this, v).first;
}
```

This relies on the function implemented immediately above it, divmod.  Implemented as follows:

```
friend pair<BigInt, BigInt> BigInt::divmod(const BigInt &a1, const BigInt &b1) {
    ... Do Things

    return make_pair(q, r / norm);
}
```

I've left out the code before the return statement.

I am writing this using VC++15.  When I hover over the error produced by `return divmod(...).first;`, Intellisense says:

```
Error: more than once instance of overloaded function "divmod" matches the argument list:
    function "divmod(const BigInt &a1, const BigInt &b1)"
    function "divmod(const BigInt &a1, const BigInt &b1)"
    argument types are: (const BigInt &a1, const BigInt &b1)
```

`*this` is set via the constructor:

```
BigInt::BigInt(long long v) {
    *this = v;
}
```

Any assistance you can provide would be helpful.  I am able to provide more information if necessary.

For the sake of information, the original program was written in C and implemented in a struct rather than as a C++ class as I've done.

**[Edit]**

I was informed that I am using the function divmod as both a friend and member of class BigInt.  To combat this, I took off the `friend` classifier and am simply leaving it as a `public pair<>` function.  Below is the code relevant to this example

```
#includes and namespaces
class BigInt {
    # Private Members

public:
    BigInt(long long v){
        *this = v
    }

    pair<BigInt, BigInt> BigInt::divmod(const BigInt &a1, const BigInt &b1) {
        ... Do things

        return make_pair(q, r / norm);
    }

    BigInt BigInt::operator / (const BigInt &v) const {
        return divmod(*this, v).first;
    }
};
```

In doing this, Intellisense gives me a new error.

```
the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "BigInt::divmod"
object type is: const BigInt
```

It is worth noting that I am not done "copying" over the code and I am missing several more functions (mostly operator overloads).  That is why at this time I am using the Intellisense errors instead of the compiler errors (even though they are just a shorter version of the errors that Intellisense gives).

In the error it mentions that I am providing a qualifier being provided to the function is invalid (and doesn't tell me which parameter it is addressing).  Could this mean that the `*this = v` line in the constructor isn't working because it's not a constant value?

Please let me know if I can give you any more information!

Comment: Could be an intellisense bug. Do you get a similar error from the actual compiler?  (If so, post that output instead)

Comment: @M.M Yup! `more than one instance of overloaded function "divmod" matches the argument list:`

Comment: You probably do actually have two matching `divmod` functions in your code then.  (Perhaps one member and one non-member).   Post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you need assistance in finding it.  Some compilers will give the file/line number of each function

Comment: `divmod` is both a `friend` and a member of `BigInt`, pick one.

Comment: @user657267 That's actually a really helpful piece of insight.  I didn't know exactly what a "friend" function was until I investigated further.
I will edit the post with a new error type that was returned.

Comment: I'm confused by your divmod function, judging by the signature, I think you want to be a `friend` or `static`, not a member.  If it's a member, I'm not sure what `a.divmod(b, c)` would mean.  The fact that you call it like `a.divmod(a, c)` just adds to the weirdness.

Comment: @NickMedovich if you're calling `divmod` from a `const` member function you'l need to make it `const` too: `pair<BigInt, BigInt> BigInt::divmod(const BigInt &a1, const BigInt &b1) const`. As Mooing Duck points out though your function definitions are a little confusing.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I'm not sure where you're seeing that.  It's called via the return statement in the overloaded operator.  I also removed the `friend` classifier from it to leave it as a `public` function in my edit (the lower part of the post).  If I'm missing something, I invite you to show me.  Sorry

Comment: @MooingDuck.  You are correct, however.  I don't like the way the program is structured very much.  I am loosely copying an example from code someone else got working (that was initially in C's structs).  I plan to see how it works and then go back through and change a good portion of it.

Comment: @user657267.  That actually makes the execution work correctly.  If you'd like to phrase that as an answer, I could give you the credit for it.  I'm not sure how to the example code compiled and ran without that there.  Perhaps they forgot to retrofit their code.
@MooingDuck I actually will be changing it to a static function as it doesn't need to be accessed outside of the class, but as it must be a member, doesn't that disqualify it from being a `friend` function?

Comment: @NickMedovich It sounds like you want it to be a `friend` function afterall, just get rid of `BigInt::` and add `friend` back. Also you shouldn't use fully qualified names inside the class definition when declaring member functions, for instance `BigInt BigInt::operator/` should just be `BigInt operator/`. Depending on how your class is defined I get the feeling that a lot of these functions should be non-member, non-friend functions but it's impossible to tell without a complete definition and use example.

Comment: @user657267  I'll provide a pastebin of the code so far below.  The top half will be the header (h) file, and the latter half is will be the source (cpp) file.
I have had problems with having the definitions of functions in one file and the implementations in another without providing the ClassName::function() setup.  Out of curiosity, why would it be beneficial for me to use it as a friend function?
[link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3cZuSTpc)

Comment: Now that we can see your source the problem is clear: You are redefining the `BigInt` class in your cpp file causing all sorts of ODR havoc. The only thing that should be in this file is the member function definitions.

Comment: Observe that `operator /` has *one* argument and `divmod` has *two*. Why one of these thing is different from the other?

Comment: @user657267 "ODR havoc" There is a redefinition of a class in the same TU. This simply must not compile.

Comment: Do not repeat the definition of `class BigInt` in your .cpp file

Comment: I removed the redefinition of the class, but just for some clarification, that wouldn't cause it to not compile.  That was the way I have been declaring my objects in h and cpp files for a while now.  It's never given me any compilation problems.  However, I shall follow convention and not do so.